# How to change display orientation on the fly

Tags: display, imx8, weston

I am using IMX8MM with yocto 5.4.70 xwayland. I want to rotate display on the fly means without restarting weston service. Can someone will provide a lead?

I can rotate display by making changes in weston.ini but it needs to restart the weston service.

Thanks & Regards,

Ajita